# sqlalchemy group by date using sqlite

Tags: python, sqlite, flask, sqlalchemy

I have a table named Journal as shown:

```
class Journal(db.Model):
    id=db.Column(db.Integer,primary_key=True)
    title=db.Column(db.String(50),index=True,unique=True)
    body=db.Column(db.String(140),index=True,unique=True)
    timestamp=db.Column(db.DateTime,index=True,default=datetime.utcnow)
    emotion=db.Column(db.Integer,index=True,unique=True)
    user_id=db.Column(db.Integer,db.ForeignKey('user.id'))

    def __repr__(self):
        return f'Journal {self.title}: {self.body}'
```

I would like to go group all the journals from the database in a dictionary format. E.g.

```
{
 12-June-2020:[j1,j2,j3..], 
 13-June-2020:[j4,j5..],
 ...
}
```

How do I go about that?

Comment: Have you considered running a query with the appropriate filter(s) and then just looping through the results and adding each object to the corresponding dict entry? GROUP BY constructs in SQL are intended to return *aggregates* of columns (e.g., MIN, MAX, COUNT) based on groups of rows, not return individual rows themselves. You'll be pulling down all of the rows anyway, so it's really just a matter of "filing" the objects however you like.

Comment: What did you try?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
db.session.query(func.strftime("%Y-%m-%d", Journal.timestamp),
    func.count(Journal.id)).\
    group_by(func.strftime("%Y-%m-%d",
        Journal.timestamp)).filter(Journal.author==current_user).all()
```

This queries for two columns: timestamp and id columns in journal table. The two columns are then grouped based on the dates that they written and filtered so that you only get journals written by the current user.

Comment: While this code may resolve the OP's issue, it's better to include an explanation on how your code addresses the OP's issue. This way, future visitors can learn from your post, & apply it to their own code. SO is not a coding service, but a resource for knowledge. High quality, complete answers reinforce this idea, and are more likely to be upvoted. These features, plus the requirement that all posts be self-contained, are some strengths of SO as a platform that differentiates us from forums. You can edit to add additional info &/or to supplement your explanations with source documentation.

Comment: You're not obligated to do so, but is it possible to write this code on multiple lines, so that scrolling is not required in order to see all the code? Sometimes it simply not possible, but if so, it might be easier to read, and thus attract more attention and up votes..